# access analytics from server side

Tags: vast, advertisement-server

This is the first time I ask a question here and I am so new to video field so please forgive me if my question is so dumb but I have researched a lot and the documentation is not really clear to me.

We add video ads to websites' videos, I want to know if we can access any analytics information (like the ones available when they use our own company player). I found something about pixels but not sure if I got the concept correctly. Is that like you the server asks the player to send it some extra info? Do we need to manipulate any settings on player?

Many thanks again sorry for a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VAST is template format to serve video ad over players. Player needs to be VAST Compliant.

In VAST you give tracking pixel to be fired on certain video events. Like, Video Start, Video First Quartile, Video End.

So VAST is just standard, Player must be VAST Friendly and you should provide tracking events to be fired on that specific ad.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So if the player does send me back the reports, I can access them, right?